# How can I pass 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded params' via GET via response redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, oauth

I have a form like so:

```
            <form action="@Model.AuthUrl" method="GET" class="login-bottom">
                <p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="Model.AppKey" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="@Model.RedirectUri" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="@ViewBag.State" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</button>
                </p>
            </form>
```

And we use it in our app to perform third-party OAuth authentication. This works fine. However, we occasionally run into a problem with the `@ViewBag.State` variable. This variable holds a value we generate in order to prevent cross-site forgery. So we validate this value when the third party directs us back to the `@Model.RedirectUri` (hosted in our domain).

The problem occurs when this page has been sitting on the user's screen for more than 20 minutes (we store the `@ViewBag.State` variable in the `Session` for later validation, which expires after 20 minutes). Basically, the `state` variable in the session becomes stale.

After the client authenticates and is redirected back to our site, we check the state value, and if it's been 20 minutes, that value is gone, so our system generates an error and directs them to authenticate again.

I would like to be able to pass the form variables to the third party auth page dynamically, right as the user clicks the button. My first thought is to wrap this in a controller and do a `return Response.Redirect();` to the third party auth page. However, the third party auth requires that we pass in those variables you see in the form via `application/x-www-form-urlencoded params`, and I can't seem to find a way to pass those variables in that manner. Is there a way to pass these variables in that manner via a `Response.Redirect`?

Or is there a better way to handle this flow so that I don't allow the state variable to get stale? (preferrably without client-side scripts)

Comment: Could you use HttpClient ot HttpWebRequest for sending data?

Comment: You can't. A redirect response is handled by the client which (if is a web browser) just executes a GET request to the provided `Location` (without a body). The only solution I can think of is by leveraging the use of javascript client-side.

Comment: Thanks @Federico Dipuma. Do you know, is this standard when consuming authentication services via a third party? It just seems odd that there is no way to direct the user to the auth page without the possibility of the variables becoming stale.